# How can I write a single Makefile for both Windows and Mac that sets an environment variable?

Tags: windows, docker, makefile, environment-variables

We have the following in our Makefile, which runs well under Mac and Linux platforms ...

```
test:
        export MY_USERNAME=`grep MY_USERNAME tests/.test_env | cut -d'=' -f 2-`; docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit
```

However, on Windows (after installing Make for Windows) the above fails an error complaining about "export" not being recognized.  Evidently the syntax for setting variables on Windows is "SET".

How do we write a single Makefile that can run different commands based on the OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I propose to use `make`'s `export` instead of `sh`'s export and `make`'s `$(shell)` instead of `sh`'s subshell:

```
export MY_USERNAME=$(shell grep MY_USERNAME tests/.test_env | cut -d'=' -f 2-)
test:
        docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit
```

> How do we write a single Makefile that can run different commands based on the OS?

I use this check:

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
  # Windows part
  example_cmd:=set
  ...
else
  # UNIX (Linux/FreeBSD/MacOS) part
  example_cmd:=export
  ...
endif
```

In windows there is always environment variable `OS=Windows_NT`, but this solution assumes that the `OS` is never used as an argument or a variable.